# How to execute war task only if a property equals to a particular value

Tags: ant, build.xml

I have multiple apps in my environment. I want the code in the build.xml such that the war file is to be built only if a property is equal to a particular value. Here I am reading the property=value pair from the console.

For example, I can assign val1, val2, val3 for a property prop1. But if prop1 is equal to val1 then only the war file is to be generated for the application I have hard coded in the build.xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the `war` task in a conditional target:

```
<condition property="val1.set">
    <equals arg1="${prop1}" arg2="val1" />
</condition>

<target name="build-war-val1" if="val1.set">
    <war ... />
</target>
```

See https://ant.apache.org/manual/targets.html for samples.

Comment: Excellent.  100% Worked. Thank you Manouti. But hope the opening target line should not end with "/>" while you have closing target tag. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: Right, that was a typo.